# Removing Un needed Whitespacing

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a view with 2 Listview's one for a Overall Invoice and one holding all the details of the items that were on the invoice(Cart items)

You'll notice theres this huge white space between the main order and the items list, I cant seem to get rid of the spacing, Without setting hard value's which I'd like to avoid. Anyone got any idea's?

Is the Listview just taking up space for another item but only contains one maybe?

Just to elaborate a little I can give the top Listview a HeightRequest of lets say around 310 to get the spacing right but I'm looking for a way that doesnt require me to set. a hard value that might distort on certain phones

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Spacing="0" Opacity="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Margin="4,0,4,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Main Order" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <ListView x:Name="SingleOrderList"
                      BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"

                      VerticalOptions="Start"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="4,0,4,0" Padding="27">
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">


                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="ID:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding id }" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Mail:" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding billing.email }" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Date:" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding date_created }" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Status:" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding status }" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>

                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding total, StringFormat='Total R:{0,5:#,0.00}' }"
                                                          FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Label Text="ITEMS" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                      x:Name="Lineorders"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10" Padding="20">
                                    <StackLayout
                                        Spacing="0"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Product:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding name }" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          FontSize="Large" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Price:" />
                                                    <Span
                                                        Text="{ Binding price,StringFormat={}{0:0.####################}}"
                                                        FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Sku:" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding sku }" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>

                                                    <Span
                                                        Text="{ Binding total , StringFormat='Total R:{0,5:#,0.00}' }"
                                                        FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Quantity:" />
                                                    <Span Text="{ Binding quantity }" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                          FontSize="Medium" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

What im looking for without HeightRequest

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout
                Margin="4,0,4,0"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Opacity="1"
                Spacing="0"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Title"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Main Order"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <ListView
                    x:Name="SingleOrderList"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Frame
                                        Margin="4,0,4,0"
                                        Padding="5,10,5,5"
                                        BackgroundColor="White"
                                        CornerRadius="20">
                                        <StackLayout
                                            BackgroundColor="LightSeaGreen"
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            Spacing="0">
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Large"
                                                            Text="ID:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Large"
                                                            Text="23" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="Mail:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding billing.email}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="Date:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding date_created}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="Status:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding status}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>

                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding total, StringFormat='Total R:{0,5:#,0.00}'}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Title"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="ITEMS"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <ListView
                    x:Name="Lineorders"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Frame
                                        Margin="10"
                                        Padding="5,10,5,5"
                                        BackgroundColor="White"
                                        CornerRadius="20">
                                        <StackLayout
                                            BackgroundColor="Red"
                                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                            Spacing="0"
                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Large"
                                                            Text="Product:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Large"
                                                            Text="{Binding name}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="Price:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding price, StringFormat={}{0:0.####################}}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="Sku:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding sku}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>

                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding total, StringFormat='Total R:{0,5:#,0.00}'}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="Quantity:" />
                                                        <Span
                                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                            FontSize="Medium"
                                                            Text="{Binding quantity}" />
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Little confused whats changed besides the backgroundcolors? and I did try either way No luck thanks tho!

Comment: VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" for StackLayout and ListView Also

Comment: Ah I did try that Its not responding I found a topic regarding this being a actuall issue with list-views

Comment: I think maybe we're miss understanding one another ima show u what I want it to be like By using Set values